# Using keypoints to compute object similarities

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to get the location of a certain object in an image taken with a camera. Template matching will not do in this case, because i need a scale/rotation invariant solution.

So i'm now using the FAST algorithm from OpenCV to detect keypoints in my image, which seems to be working good.

But what next? I have a 'template image' of the object that i want to detect. I can imagine that i have to detect the keypoints of this template image too, and then compare it showhow to the image taken with the camera. Is this what i have to do next and if so, what functions can i use for that?? (i'm using OpenCV)

Or is there another way of doing this?

So how can i use the keypoints to detect a certain object in my image?

Comment: You can look at the last 3 tutorials from this page, maybe they can be of use to you : http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html

Comment: @AdrianPopovici Thanks, i tried "Features2D + Homography to find a known object", it works excellent. The downside is that its extremly slow. But that's probably because i'm on an iphone. I'm gonna try the last one too to see if that is faster. Thanks anyway, you pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using **FAST** for detecting **keypoints**, that is OK.

Now the next step is using a **Descriptor Extractator**. What a descriptor extractor is? Is an algorithm that generates a description of a keypoint that makes this keypoint recognizable by a **matcher**. Famous descriptors are **SIFT, FREAK**...

After you find descriptors in the template image and in the query image, you will need a matcher. The matcher will tell you which descriptors are the same.

Note that SIFT requires an euclidean-distance-based matcher (FLANN), but FREAK or other binary descriptors require a hamming-distance-based matcher.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ORB features instead. They are designed to be faster.
Also, take a look at the [CARD descriptors](http://cvlab.jp/).

Comment: I tried to implement the ORB method, but the app crashes everytime i try it. It keeps crashing when i try to do a match. -- Brute Force method:http://pastebin.com/BvnFQgcY --- flannBased: http://pastebin.com/1RrCv0QL -- Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @Adi Shavit dead link

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try SIFT keypoint description

[VLfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html)

[Rob Hess](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/sift-library-places-2nd-in-acm-mm-10-ossc/)

the second one is opencv based .